# BMI calculation syntax with javascript inside dynamics

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, calc

I'd like to create a simple BMI calculator (MS Dynamics 2011)

I have 3 fields:

```
1: persons height (precision 2 - decimal formatted text box)
2. persons weight (precision 2 - decimal formatted text box)
3. BMI result - This field will display the BMI result. (also precision 2 - decimal)
```

I believe I need to check the oncreate event on both fields 1 & 2, to launch a javascript function to carry out the calculation.
However, I am very new to both dynamics and java-script, and need some help.

I think something along these lines could be close.  Can someone assist?

```
function BMICheck()
{
var Bmiresult = weight/(height/100*height/100);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_bmiresulttextbox").setValue((Math.round(Bmiresult*100)/100).toString(    ));

}
```

I think I understand the logic OK, syntax is my main issue.

Thanks!

Updated answer with javascript:

```
function BMICheck()
{

var Bmival = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("crm_heightbox_decimal")/("crm_weightbox_decimal")/100*("crm_weightbox_decimal")/100);
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("crm_bmiresultbox").setValue((Math.round(Bmival*100)/100));

 }
```

Comment: The field name "bmiresulttextbox" is not right. Use the logical name; something like "new_bmiresulttextbox". Have you created a CRM solution?

Comment: Ideally you would work through a solution instead of the default solution; then the prefix would be your own prefix, like bbh_bmiresulttextbox. The advantage is that you can keep track of customizations, they will run away with you if you work only through the default solution.

Comment: I understand, thanks. :)  Any tips on my question?

Comment: The function is good. All you need to do is add it as a web resource, and add the web resource to the form you are working with.

Comment: I've only used webresources so far as a label hack, can you describe what I need to do to add as a resource? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript is ok, except for `ToString` as Daryl already pointed out.
I would add a check for `height` and `weight` to prevent null values (the check if is a positive number can be avoided if the fields have a minimum value setting greater than 0.00)

```js
function BMICheck()
{
    var weight = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_weight").getValue();
    var height = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_height").getValue();
    if (weight != null & height != null) {
        var bmi = weight/(height/100*height/100);
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_bmi").setValue(Math.round(bmi*100)/100);
    }
    else {
        alert("Need to insert Weight and Height!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, my syntax was pretty good, but this is how I should be doing it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript looks fine to me.  The .toString() is unnecessary.

A helpful note about javascript and CRM, is to use F12 to debug your javascript in IE.  You can set breakpoints and see what exactly is happening.

If it is generating an error, include it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Learn how solutions work and work through a solution: http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/05/28/dynamics-crm-2011-solutions-part-1/
2. Add a JavaScript web resource to your new solution

   - Open your solution, or the default solution (through Customize the System)
   - Click Web Resources
   - Click New
     Choose Script(JScript)
3. Click Text Editor and past your function in
4. Add the web resource to the form

   - Open to form
   - Click Form Properties
   - Add the web resource as a library
5. Add BMICheck to the onChange event on height and weight

   - Open the form
   - Click the height field
   - Click Change Properties
   - Click Events
   - Add your function
   - Repeat for the weight field
   - NOTE: make use of Guido's null check to avoid errors

Comment: Great, thanks Bvrce.  I actually managed this much, although I just manually loaded in the javascript into an existing library.